# java 8 android sdk wont install

Tags: java, android

I have searched for 3hrs now and still can't find the answer. I'm trying to install Android SDK with Java 8, I have tried to set a path and it is set, I have tried hitting back and then next again,nothing is working. Is it Java 8 or what. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, Java 8 is not yet supported. It supports Java 7, and not fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure Java 8 is working with Android SDK at this moment.

You should rather use Java 6 or Java 7.